How can I prove such eigenvalue property of a kronecker sum?
I was asked to show that every eigenvalue of $C=A \otimes I_n + I_m \otimes B$ is the sum of an eigenvalue of $A$ and other of $B$ (Both are square matrices with sizes $m$ and $n$ respectively), the furthest I could go was only to show that all possible sums of eigenvalues from both matrices are eigenvalues of $C$, but I am struggling to demonstrate that $\textbf{all}$ eigenvalues of C can be depicted as such sum.

Hint: $A$ and $B$ have bases of generalized eigenvectors. Say ${u_i}$, ${v_i}$ are bases of $\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of generalized eigenvectors for $A,B$.  Show that $u_i \otimes v_j$ is a generalized eigenvector for $C$.  Since there are $m \times n$ of them and they are independent, you have exhausted all eigenvalues.

@JairTaylor I got the idea, but one question emerged. Suppose A and B were to form each just one jordan chain, then $u_1 \otimes v_1$ would be an eigenvector. But $C(u_2 \otimes v_1)= (\lambda_a + \lambda_b)(u_2 \otimes v_1) + (u_1 \otimes v_1)$ and $C(u_1 \otimes v_2)= (\lambda_a + \lambda_b)(u_1 \otimes v_2) + (u_1 \otimes v_1)$, which means that $u_2 \otimes v_1$ and $u_1 \otimes v_2$ would not constitute different jordan chains in C since both share the same eigenvalue (of order 1). If this isn't wrong, wouldn't it hinder the generalized eigenvectors linear independency?

You can't write the Kronecker sum as $C=A \otimes I_n + I_n \otimes B$ with $A$ and $B$ having "sizes m and n respectively".    All you need here is to simultaneously triangularize $A \otimes I_n$ and $I_n \otimes B$ [you should always consider this with two commuting matrices] and check the diagonal of the sum; no need to use a Jordan form.

@user8675309 I fixed the typo. Indeed, simultaneously triangularizing solves the problem quite easily. Still, I'm not able to spot the error in the last comment I did if I insisted in trying to prove , for different values of $i$ and $j$, that $u_i \otimes v_j$ would be linear independent generalized eigenvectors for C (as described by Jair).

Say $\{u_i\}$ and $\{v_i\}$ are bases of generalized eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$ respectively.  That is, we have eigenvalues $\lambda_i, \mu_i$ with  $(A-\lambda_i I)^n u_i  = 0$ and $(B - \mu_i I)^m v_i = 0$.
Then $(A \otimes I + B \otimes I) - (\lambda_i + \mu_j) (I \otimes I) = (A - \lambda_iI) \otimes I + I \otimes (B - \mu_jI)$ and then, since the two summands commute,
$$\left((A - \lambda_iI) \otimes I + I \otimes (B - \mu_jI)\right)^{m+n} (u_i \otimes v_j)$$ can be written $$\sum_{k=0}^{m+n} {m+n \choose k} ((A - \lambda_i I) \otimes I)^k (I \otimes (B - \mu_jI))^{m+n-k}(u_i \otimes v_j)$$
and every summand is $0$, since either $k \geq n$ or $m+n-k \geq m$. This shows $u_i \otimes v_j$ is a generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_i + \mu_j$.  Since we have $mn$  linearly independent generalized eigenvectors, this must exhaust the set of all eigenvalues.
